# Issue adding new projects to source control TF10175: The team project does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc

We use TFS for our source control. Everything worked ok for a while then we started getting errors when adding existing projects to source control.

When I add the files to source control then try to check them in I get this error - TF10175: The team project does not exist.

Then the files look like they are checked in but any attempt to edit them gets this error: TF402484 - team project has been deleted.

[image]

I can see the project in Source Control Explorer, but when I close visual studio and go back in it's gone and doesn't exist in source control at all.

It's happening for every project so we can't add anything new to source control.

Comment: Did you validate whether or not the team project was deleted, as is indicated in the error message?

Comment: Could you reproduce that issue in other machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Try adding the existing projects to source control in another client
  machine.
- Delete the workspace and created a new one, then check it again.

  `Team Explorer Home` --> Under `Solution` --> Click the arrow down
  behind `workspace` --> `Manage Workspaces`... --> Select the specific
  workspace then `Remove`

  **Note**: *This will remove all your local mappings. Therefore you should checkin all changes before deleting it.*
- Look at `Excluded Changes` section under `Pending Changes` and check
  if there are any files which belong to a **deleted folder**. If yes,
  right click at the file name and choose **Undo**.

  [image]

Also reference this thread : [Visual Studio TFS: TF10175 During Add Solution To Source Control in Visual Studio How To Fix](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1024&fb_ref=Default)